# NSMutableURLRequest setCachePolicy is not used

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

I have an `NSURLMutableURLRequest` where I call

```
[urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData];
```

When I po `[urlRequest cachePolicy]` it is always 1.

What is the getter doing that could force it to return 1?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this policy has not been implemented yet (navigate `NSURLMutableURLRequest` by means of cmd+click and find `NSURLRequestCachePolicy`).

```
enum
{
    NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,

    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,

    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,

    NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5, // Unimplemented
};
typedef NSUInteger NSURLRequestCachePolicy;
```

This is also well documented in [NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/). There is also a radar at http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1755401.

Comment: The policy still isn't working for my UIWebView using NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad. The UIWebView returns 2 for the first request inside shouldStartLoadWithRequest for the request cachePolicy but subsequent requests return 1 for the cachePolicy